# Autocomplete field with CakePHP 2.X

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an autocomplete file using cakephp 2.3.7.
There're tons of tutorials but most of them are for cake 1.3 or so.

I've found some for cake 2.X like this one (http://hitechcyberabad.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/autocomplete-in-cakephp-22x-using-jquery.html), but none of them work for me.

I had to edit the code of cities_dropdown.ctp of the tutorial:

```
<div class="contacts search form">
<fieldset>
<legend></legend>
    <?php //paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
    $this->Form->create('Contact', array('type'=>'post','action' => 'find'));

    echo $this->Form->input('city', array(
        'empty' => 'Pick a city',
        'label' => 'City',
        'option'=> $cities,
        'id' => 'city',
        'autocomplete' => 'on'));
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Search'));
    ?>
   </fieldset>

</div>
<script>
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/cake/contacts/find",
  minLength: 2,
  delay: 2
});
</script>
```

The rest of the code is like in the tutorial.

I don't get any error message, it simply doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: `source: "/cake/contacts/find"` If that doesn't return data in the format that [autocomplete expects](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) - it won't work.

Comment: I've also tried with the complete route but it still not working

Comment: Don't know what that means, you are providing no information. e.g. what does the url `/cake/contacts/find?term=abc` return - are you even _emitting_ a request when you type in your autocomplete form input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you debug the response of the ajax call? Use the debug tools of chrome or Firebug for Firefox to debug the requests or use http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to do so.

I'm pretty sure your json response is not correct and probably containing an error. Also the tutorial you've linked doesn't show the best way to deal with json in CakePHP, see [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) of the manual. Debug your response and update your question with it.

Comment: I just realised that I'm not getting any AJAX call because it throws me the next error message:


ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$("#city").autocomplete({

Comment: Well, there you go: Fix the javascript. In this case it looks like jquery is not loaded at all or loaded at the time you try to access $.

Comment: I loaded as the tutorial says, adding the "$this->Html->script(...)" line in default.ctp
Anyway, I've loaded it again and then I have this error: TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
$("#city").autocomplete({

Comment: The tutorial is obviously not one of the best. Wrap your script in $(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
}); or better use $this->Html->scriptBlock("...", array('inline' => false); Also makre sure the jquery lib is loaded *BEFORE* your code.

Comment: I couldn't make it work, but I found another tutorial and I finally get it (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/matt_1/2011/08/07/yet_another_jquery_autocomplete_helper_2).

Comment: check out this example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple autocomplete code

cities.ctp code

```
<? echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
   echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.10.2');
   echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui');
   echo $this->Html->css('style.css');
 ?>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?=$cities?>];
    $( "#city_from" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>

<?php echo $this->Form->input("city_from", array('required'=>'true',  'class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'city_from', 'placeholder'=>'City or airport', 'label'=>'<span class="opensans size13">Flying from</span>'));?>
```

Controller code

```
       //Airport cities string section starts
        $this->loadModel('AirportCity');
        $cities=$this->AirportCity->find('list',array('fields'=>'AirportCity.city_name'));
        $strCities='"'.implode('","',$cities).'"';
        $this->set('cities',$strCities);
        //Airport cities string section ends
```

for more assistance refer http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/